# Where is a list of possible errors?

Tags: node.js

Node.JS is a great tool, but it's documentation is not very in-depth. I want to handle errors in my application correctly, but I don't know what errors to expect.

In particular I want to know which errors are emitted by:

- `http.IncomingMessage`
- `http.ServerResponse`
- `http.ClientRequest`
- `net.Socket`.

Does any one know the circumstances in which these objects will emit error events?

Comment: I'm only using Node.JS by itself, not any framework like connect or express

Comment: If you really want to know all Node.JS errors I suggest you to read its source code. You need need that for your application?

Comment: @PedroNasser - I'm doing that now but I was hoping there was a list somewhere.